# Reduce Application Lag while using shadows in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, shadow, lag

I am working on a 3D map in SceneKit. When I enable the Cast Shadow Property of a directional light in SceneKit, the shadows appear, but the application becomes very slow.

How do I reduce the lag while still maintaining shadows in the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Fake Shadows](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c) (shadows generated as a texture in 3D authoring or 2D authoring app) rather than `True Shadow Map`. To apply fake shadows as a texture for 3D plane use `PNG` file format with premultiplied alpha channel (`RGB * A`). It considerably reduces Processing and Memory Usage when using shadows in RealityKit or SceneKit.

[image]