# Add shadow to SCNPlane

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have `ARKit` artwork app. And I want my artworks to have a shadow just behind it. The shadow mustn't be dynamic. Just static shadow.

I've tried to add a plane behind the artwork. And set a shadow to it. But I discovered that it is not easy.

Can you help me?

```
let shadow = SCNPlane(width: artwork.size.width * 0.0254 + 0.03, height: artwork.size.height * 0.0254 + 0.015)

let layer = CALayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: shadow.width, height: shadow.height))
layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
layer.shadowOpacity = 1
layer.shadowOffset = .zero
layer.shadowRadius = 10

shadow.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer
```

The shadow should be like in `UIKit's` `UIView`. But this code just doesn't work.

I need something like [image: this]

Comment: You shouldn't need any of that code you posted. Shadows are setup on the lights not the objects. You can start by setting `castsShadow` to true.

Comment: @CraigSiemens I don't need a dynamic shadow. I just need a static shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**.

In order to cast and receive a shadows from 3D lights, you have to use a 3D primitives (like cube, sphere, cylinder, etc), or 3D models in such formats as `.usdz`, `.dae` or `.obj`.

## Shadow on a visible plane.

Use the following code to test how light generates shadows for 3D geometry:

```
let scene = SCNScene()

let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light!.type = .spot
lightNode.light!.castsShadow = true
lightNode.light!.shadowMode = .deferred
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: -1, y: 0, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi/2)
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 20, z: 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

let sphereNode = SCNNode()
sphereNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -2, z: 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

let planeNode = SCNNode()
planeNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 15, height: 15)
planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: -5, z: 0)
planeNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: -1, y: 0, z: 0, w: CGFloat.pi/2) 

planeNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

## Shadow on invisible plane.

In case you need an **invisible plane** that **receives a shadow**, use the following code:

```
planeNode.geometry?.materials.first?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
planeNode.geometry?.materials.first?.writesToDepthBuffer = true
planeNode.geometry?.materials.first?.lightingModel = .constant
```

## Fake shadow.

And if you want to use a **fake shadow** written as a `.png` (png file format can hold 4 channels) texture on geometry (with a premultiplied alpha channel – RGB x A), use the following approach:

```
planeNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "shadow.png")

lightNode.light!.castsShadow = false
```

Here's [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070521/reduce-application-lag-while-using-shadows-in-scenekit/51181063#51181063) on fake shadows.

And here's your premultiplied shadow in `.png` format (just drag-and-drop it on your desktop):

[image]

> You can change its size and transparency and, of course, you can blur it.

Comment: I think that my custom node(artwork) doesn't cast a shadow. I have added the planeNode to my artwork node(behind), so the plane node is a child of the artwork. Is that a problem?

Comment: What your node "artwork" is? Is it SCN primitive or anything else? Please, show it in your code.

Comment: can’t show you code right now, but it’s just a SCNBox with image as content.

Comment: Due to the fact that I can't see your code and I can't see the possible pitfall in it, the simplest way for you is to make a child node independent from parent node.

Comment: ok thanks. I think the best way here for me is to use **fake shadow**. Do you know what images I can use?

Comment: I updated the answer one more time. What do you mean, saying "images"? I supplied my answer with necessary info about fake shadowing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195320/discussion-between-andrii-moisol-and-argeo).